# Laravel Eloquent Relationship Through Another Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

I have the following database tables:

Seasons

- id
- number

Teams

- id
- name

Standings

- id
- season_id
- team_id

The question is, how could I get all of the teams in a season through the standings table. At the moment I am getting all of the teams this way:

```
$teams = [];

$standings = $season->standings;

foreach($standings as $standing){

     $teams[] = $standing->team;

}
```

Is there a way I could do this using Eloquent relationships? I have tried HasManyThrough with no success. These are what my models look like currently:

```
class Season extends Eloquent{

    public function standings(){

        return $this->hasMany('Standing');

    }

}

class Standing extends Eloquent{

    public function team(){

        return $this->belongsTo('Team');

    }

}

class Team extends Eloquent{

    public function standings(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('Standing');

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your relationships look a little off.  Here is all the relationships you should need though only the `belongsToMany` ones are required for this specific scenario of finding all the teams in a season.

```
class Season extends Eloquent {

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Team', 'Standings');
    }

    public function standings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Standing');
    }
}

class Team extends Eloquent {

    public function seasons()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Season', 'Standings');
    }

    public function standings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Standing');
    }
}

class Standing extends Eloquent {

    public function team()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Team');
    }

    public function season()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Season');
    }
}
```

You would use the `belongsToMany` relationship rather than a `hasManyThrough` to query all the teams in a season.  That would look something like...

```
Season::with('teams')->find($season_id);

foreach($season->teams as $team) {
    echo $team->name;
}
```

Comment: @ user3158900 can you say if this example also aplies to this situation? if i have a campaingn that belongsToMany Columns and columns hasMany Values and Values belongsToMany Campaingns

Comment: I don't think so but I can't be sure without seeing the schema.  If you create a new question with your schema, I will be happy to look.

Comment: @ user3158900 my question is here stackoverflow.com/q/30371161/219626

Comment: @user3158900 would you mind taking a look at a similar question here? Thanks in advance:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687503/laravel-eloquent-relationship-through-tables